# How to check whether UPnP server is running or not?

Tags: linux, upnp, fedora12, upnpx, gupnp

I am using platinum UPnP stack, and I am trying to check whether the UPnP service is running or not. This is the example code from Platinum that I am running. However, I want to debug whether the Device is added or not. How can I see or debug whether the device has really started the UPnP or not.I am using Fedora core - 12.

```c
int
main(int /* argc */, char** /* argv */)
{
    PLT_UPnP upnp;

    PLT_DeviceHostReference device(new PLT_LightSampleDevice("Platinum Light Bulb"));

#ifdef TEST_EMBEDDED_DEVICE
    PLT_DeviceDataReference device2(new PLT_LightSampleDevice("Platinum Light Bulb embed 1"));
    device->AddEmbeddedDevice((PLT_DeviceDataReference&)device2);
    
    PLT_DeviceDataReference device3(new PLT_LightSampleDevice("Platinum Light Bulb embed 2"));
    device->AddEmbeddedDevice(device3);
#endif

    upnp.AddDevice(device);
    upnp.Start();

    char buf[256];
    while (gets(buf)) {
        if (*buf == 'q')
            break;
    }

    upnp.Stop();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question. There is a utility called UPnP Inspector to check whether the UPnP server is running or not. On a Fedora core, this can be installed as 
sudo yum install upnp-inspector